# Change Content-Disposition of existing S3 object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, metadata

In S3 REST API I am adding metadata to an existing object by using the PUT (Copy) command and copying a key to the same location with `'x-amz-metadata-directive' = 'REPLACE'`

What I want to do is change the download file name by setting:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=foo.bar;
```

**This sets the metadata correctly but when I download the file it still uses the key name instead of 'foo.bar'**

I use a software tool S3 Browser to view the metadata  and **it looks correct** (apart from `'Content-Disposition'` being all lower case as that's was S3 ask me to sign)

Then using S3 Browser I just pressed, then save without changing anything and now it works???

What am I missing how come setting a metadata `'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=foo.bar;'` from my web app does not work but does work from S3 Browser?

Comment: Shouldn't this question actually be titled something like "Change Content-Disposition of existing S3 object", since that is the actual problem it is trying to solve?

Comment: yeah probably makes more sense, I have changed the title now. However Content-Disposition and metadata are treated the same way

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edited for clarity:

**Content-Disposition must be set explicitly** and not included as `x-amz-meta-Content-Disposition`. All metadata header names must start with "x-amz-meta-" and be all lowercase.

Thanks to @Eyal for clarifying.

Original:

```
>SOLVED:
>
>The Doco at http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?RESTAuthentication.html
>
>seems to be wrong it says:
>
>Notice how the 'x-amz-' headers are sorted, white-space trimmed, converted tolowercase, and multiple headers with the same name have been joined using a comma toseparate values.
>
>Note how only the Content-Type and Content-MD5HTTPentity headers appear in the StringToSign .The otherContent-* entity headers do not.
However Content-Disposition must be set specifically and not included as : x-amz-meta-Content-Disposition
>
>It now works fine.
```

Comment: In your round-about way, you're saying that all metadata header names must start with "x-amz-meta-" and be all lowercase.  You could've just say it instead of asking us to "notice".

Answer (score 3):

here: this uses the cli to set the content-disposition header on all files in a path inside a bucket (and also sets them as public):

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/brand_img/ios/|awk {'print $4'} > objects.txt

 while read line; do aws s3api copy-object --bucket mybucket  \
--copy-source /mybucket/brand_img/ios/$line --key brand_img/ios/$line \
--metadata-directive REPLACE --metadata Content-Disposition=$line --acl public-read; done < objects.txt
```

Comment: will this incur aws copy files cost since i have 100 files in 20gb size on which i want to change content-disposition