# How do I download a file with php and the Amazon S3 sdk?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I'm trying to make it so that my script will show test.jpg in an Amazon S3 bucket through php.
Here's what I have so far:

```
require_once('library/AWS/sdk.class.php');

$s3 = new AmazonS3($key, $secret);

$objInfo = $s3->get_object_headers('my_bucket', 'test.jpg');
$obj = $s3->get_object('my_bucket', 'test.jpg', array('headers' => array('content-disposition' => $objInfo->header['_info']['content_type'])));

echo $obj->body;
```

This just dumps out the file data on the page. I think I need to also send the content-disposition header, which I thought was being done in the get_object() method, but it isn't.

Note: I'm using the SDK available here: http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/

Comment: I'm not familiar with that PHP S3 library (which one is it? Might help if you mentioned that in the question, as there are several of them.) But the fact you're speficially echoing `$obj->body` makes me think that the object you get back probably has separate headers and body, and that maybe you need to echo a Content-Type header according to the information in `$obj->header`, or something along those lines?

Comment: I'm using http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Got it to work by echo'ing out the content-type header before echo'ing the $object body.

```
$objInfo = $s3->get_object_headers('my_bucket', 'test.jpg');
$obj = $s3->get_object('my_bucket', 'test.jpg');

header('Content-type: ' . $objInfo->header['_info']['content_type']);
echo $obj->body;
```

Comment: content-disposition is a hint to the browser how to handle the file. inline, attachment, etc... content-type defines what the file IS. (image, document, text, etc..)

Comment: -@doremi thanks for solving this problem, i was struggling for quite some time with it...

Comment: @MarcB  how i send this file as a attachment in mail.. can u help me plz.. i am using PHP SDK of aws

Comment: it should be `Body`.. [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrieveObjSingleOpPHP.html)

Comment: watch out when using `echo $obj->body`, you can run out of memory with bigger files! A better way would be using
`$response['Body']->rewind();`
`while ($data = $response['Body']->read(1024)) { echo $data;}`

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html#downloading-objects

Answer (score 23):

Both of these methods work for me. The first way seems more concise.

```
    $command = $s3->getCommand('GetObject', array(
       'Bucket' => 'bucket_name',
       'Key'    => 'object_name_in_s3'  
       'ResponseContentDisposition' => 'attachment; filename="'.$my_file_name.'"'
    ));

    $signedUrl = $command->createPresignedUrl('+15 minutes');
    echo $signedUrl;
    header('Location: '.$signedUrl);
    die();
```

Or a more wordy but still functional way.

```
    $object = $s3->getObject(array(
    'Bucket' => 'bucket_name',
    'Key'    => 'object_name_in_s3'   
    ));

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    //this assumes content type is set when uploading the file.
    header('Content-Type: ' . $object->ContentType);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $my_file_name);
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');

    //send file to browser for download. 
    echo $object->body;
```

Comment: thanks@MatteoStohlman nd @Maximus    .. but how i send this file as a attachment in mail.. can u help me plz..

Comment: That's a whole different ball of wax. You wouldn't use headers because that assumes you are going to download it. You'd save the file to disk, and then attache it using your mail client. I don't have the current code for downloading files from S3, but that is the basic process. Download file and save to the server, then attach it using your mail client. 

Both are two separate processes. 

Good luck!

Comment: I am able to download file but if I open that file, it is showing that "It appears that we don't support this file format even though the file format is png,jmx,jpg". Can you please help me out in this regard? @Maximus

Comment: I'd say to check your mime type for your file and make sure it matches. But I haven't used the amazon sdk for awhile so I'm sorry I can't help you more.

Answer (score 6):

For PHP sdk3 change the last line of Maximus answer

```
    $object = $s3->getObject(array(
       'Bucket' => 'bucket_name',
       'Key'    => 'object_name_in_s3'   
    ));

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    //this assumes content type is set when uploading the file.
    header('Content-Type: ' . $object->ContentType);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $my_file_name);
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');

    //send file to browser for download. 
    echo $object["Body"];
```

Comment: I am able to download file but if I open that file, it is showing that "It appears that we don't support this file format even though the file format is png,jmx,jpg". Can you please help me out in this regard? @Raj Sharma

Answer (score 5):

If you're still looking for a relevant answer in 2019+, With AWS SDK for PHP 3.x and specifically '2006-03-01' with composer, the following worked for me

```php
...

/**
 * Download a file
 * 
 * @param   string  $object_key
 * @param   string  $file_name
 * @return  void
 */
function download($object_key, $file_name = '') {
  if ( empty($file_name) ) {
    $file_name = basename($file_path);
  }
  $cmd = $s3->getCommand('GetObject', [
    'Bucket'                        => '<aws bucket name>',
    'Key'                           => $object_key,
    'ResponseContentDisposition'    => "attachment; filename=\"{$file_name}\"",
  ]);
  $signed_url = $s3->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+15 minutes') // \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request
                ->getUri() // \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri
                ->__toString();
  header("Location: {$signed_url}");
}
download('<object key here>', '<file name for download>');
```

NOTE: This is a solution for those who would want to avoid the issues that may arise from proxying the download through their servers by using a direct download link from AWS.

Comment: Thanks for the succinct answer. It's too bad AWS doesn't provide usable quickies like this in their docs.  Also "...that may arise from proxying the download through their servers " ... like running out of memory if you are serving 800MB files. Not like that was happening to me or anything. O_o

Answer (score 1):

I added the Content-Disposition header to the getAuthenticatedUrl();

```
 // Example
 $timeOut = 3600; // in seconds
 $videoName = "whateveryoulike";
 $headers = array("response-content-disposition"=>"attachment");
 $downloadURL = $s3->getAuthenticatedUrl( FBM_S3_BUCKET, $videoName, FBM_S3_LIFETIME + $timeOut, true, true, $headers );
```

Comment: What does the "true, true" stand for?

Answer (score 0):

This script downloads all files in all directories on an S3 service, such as Amazon S3 or DigitalOcean spaces.

1. Configure your credentials (See the class constants and the code under the class)
2. Run `composer require aws/aws-sdk-php`
3. Assuming you saved this script to index.php, then run `php index.php` in a console and let it rip!

Please note that I just wrote code to get the job done so I can close down my DO account. It does what I need it to, but there are several improvements I could have made to make it more extendable. Enjoy!

---

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

class DOSpaces {

    // Find them at https://cloud.digitalocean.com/account/api/tokens
    const CREDENTIALS_API_KEY           = '';
    const CREDENTIALS_API_KEY_SECRET    = '';

    const CREDENTIALS_ENDPOINT          = 'https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com';
    const CREDENTIALS_REGION            = 'us-east-1';
    const CREDENTIALS_BUCKET            = 'my-bucket-name';

    private $client = null;

    public function __construct(array $args = []) {

        $config = array_merge([
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region'  => static::CREDENTIALS_REGION,
            'endpoint' => static::CREDENTIALS_ENDPOINT,
            'credentials' => [
                'key'    => static::CREDENTIALS_API_KEY,
                'secret' => static::CREDENTIALS_API_KEY_SECRET,
            ],
        ], $args);

        $this->client = new S3Client($config);
    }

    public function download($destinationRoot) {
        $objects = $this->client->listObjectsV2([
            'Bucket' => static::CREDENTIALS_BUCKET,
        ]);

        foreach ($objects['Contents'] as $obj){

            echo "DOWNLOADING " . $obj['Key'] . "\n";
            $result = $this->client->getObject([
                'Bucket' => 'dragon-cloud-assets',
                'Key' => $obj['Key'],
            ]);

            $this->handleObject($destinationRoot . $obj['Key'], $result['Body']);

        }
    }

    private function handleObject($name, $data) {
        $this->ensureDirExists($name);

        if (substr($name, -1, 1) !== '/') {
            echo "CREATING " . $name . "\n";
            file_put_contents($name, $data);
        }
    }

    private function ensureDirExists($name) {
        $dir = $name;
        if (substr($name, -1, 1) !== '/') {
            $parts = explode('/', $name);
            array_pop($parts);
            $dir = implode('/', $parts);
        }

        @mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
    }

}

$doSpaces = new DOSpaces([
    'endpoint' => 'https://nyc2.digitaloceanspaces.com',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => '12345',
        'secret' => '54321',
    ],
]);
$doSpaces->download('/home/myusername/Downloads/directoryhere/');
```