# How to create download link for an Amazon S3 bucket's object?

Tags: php, api, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I am learning Amazon S3 using S3 PHP Class. I have uploaded my all files to my S3 bucket, now I want to create links for each available file in my bucket.

Will the following function work for me?

```
public static function getAuthenticatedURL($bucket, $uri, $lifetime, $hostBucket = false, $https = false)
{

}

    $s3 = new S3('access-key', 'secret-key');
    $s3->getAuthenticatedURL($bucket, $uri, $lifetime, $hostBucket = false, $https = false);
```

Or another function like `get_object_url`, but `get_object_url()` not in my S3 class.

**I am using Undesigned's [Amazon S3 PHP class](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class).**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I download a file with php and the Amazon S3 sdk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389394/how-do-i-download-a-file-with-php-and-the-amazon-s3-sdk)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want the public to access the bucket, it is as simple as

http://[YourBucketName].s3.amazonaws.com/[YourFileName]

So long as you set permissions correctly.

If you're worried about download abuse, you'll want an authenticated URL (which I guess you want from your code sammple). In which case, I suggest you use the Amazon SDK: http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/ as it contains examples of what you need.

```
$s3->getObjectUrl($bucket, $filename, '5 minutes');
```

Docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_getObjectUrl

Comment: `get_object_url()` function not working with my library, what to do now.

Comment: Updated to the current public method "getObjectUrl" http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_getObjectUrl

Comment: For anyone coming here as of mid-2015 (possibly earlier), the third parameter to this method was removed in the SDK, and thus you cannot generate a signed URL this way. See https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/603 for the solution.

Answer (score 14):

The following patterns are valid for constructing S3 URLs:

```
http(s)://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<object>
http(s)://s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket>/<object>
```

Comment: Can't be used for download purposes.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389394/how-do-i-download-a-file-with-php-and-the-amazon-s3-sdk

Comment: NOTE! This will not work for you if you have security on your bucket

Answer (score 8):

In addition to [Hossein's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663238/how-to-create-download-link-for-an-amazon-s3-buckets-object/#53757853), if you want to start download immediately upon visiting the link (simulate "**Save as...**" behaviour), you need to add ResponseContentDisposition parameter alongside Bucket and Key, like so:

```
$cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', [
    'Bucket' => 'my-bucket',
    'Key' => 'testKey',
    'ResponseContentDisposition' => 'attachment; filename="custom_file_name.mp3"'
]);

$request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');

$presignedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();
```

*Note: custom filename is optional, without specifying it, downloaded file will have its S3 name.*

Answer (score 3):

If you use `aws-sdk-php v3` and your file is private.

```
$cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', [
    'Bucket' => 'my-bucket',
    'Key' => 'testKey'
]);

$request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');

$presignedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();
```

Answer (score 2):

I see that people have already responded to this but I wanted to add some more context for those who may have a secured bucket (requires access). Note, you don't have to generate the URLs if you talk directly to the S3 bucket, then you can use 'file_get_contents' etc. but it is much slower as you can't use multi curl requests (for speed). However you could use pthreads if you have a newer php release.

INSTALLATION:
Install the S3 Class file for Amazon, there are easy ways to add it using composer or just downloading the S3.php file manually.

NOT SECURED: 
(see other posts on this matter, just basically use the URL)

```
http(s)://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<object>
http(s)://s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket>/<object>
```

SECURED HTTPS (when you have your bucket protected):

```
https://amazon.com/file/you/wanted.xxx?ID:XXXXX?SIG:YYYYY
```

(1) Create a https:// url and use the multi curl tool to get them all at the same time (recommended).

A simplistic example:

```
$url = /path/to_the/file_name/file.ext  

//note check amazon to confirm the path which will contain only "_" and no spaces.

$s3 = new S3($awsAccessKeyID, $awsSecretKey);
$curls[] = $s3->get_object_url($bucketName, $uri, '1 hour');
var_dump($results = multiCurlRequest($curls));
```

more info:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_getObjectUrl
http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/documentation

FYI:

```
function multiCurlRequest($curlList = array(),$user = '', $pass = '',$timeout = self::MULTI_REQ_TIMEOUT_SECS, $retTxfr = 1) {

    if (empty($curlList) || count($curlList) == 0) return false;

    $master = curl_multi_init();
    $node_count = count($curlList);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++) {
        $ch[$i] = curl_init($curlList[$i]);
        curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout); // -- timeout after X seconds
        curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, $retTxfr);
        curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
        curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_USERPWD, "{$user}:{$pass}");
        curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_multi_add_handle($master, $ch[$i]);
    }

    // -- get all requests at once, finish when done or timeout met --
    do {  curl_multi_exec($master, $running);  }
    while ($running > 0);

    $results = array();

    // -- get results from requests --
    for ($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++) {
        $results[$i] = curl_multi_getcontent($ch[$i]);
        if ((int) curl_getinfo($ch[$i], CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) > 399 || empty($results[$i])) {
            $this->set_request(  [ ['label' => '404', 'href' => $results[$i], '404' => '1' ] ] );
            unset($results[$i]);
        }
        curl_multi_remove_handle($master, $ch[$i]);
        curl_close($ch[$i]);
    }

    curl_multi_close($master);
    if (empty($results)) return false;
    //$results = array_values($results); // -- removed as we want the original positions
    return $results;
}
```