# How to link a large file from S3 to a CakePHP 2.x request?

Tags: php, cakephp, amazon-s3

Without downloading and than sending the data in a body of the request. Is there any way how to just "stream it through"? At the moment I am limited by the memory allocated by PHP as I have to hold the content of the entire file in memory before sending it through ...

I am working on an enterprise App Store for Apple iOS apps (and android too but that is fine with a link) and they require the domain to be same as the server and the server itself is just too small for hosting so many files ... it also requires a valid SSL certificate which I have on the server.

I have tried to link directly to S3 already but it won't work, the only way to do this is to serve the files from the server, thus I have been asking about passing the file over/hiding the original location or I don't know, maybe mounting S3 as a drive?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Sending large amounts of data to a browser (other than a download) is usually not a good approach. There may be alternative solutions for your problem, which would become clear if we actually know what you're trying to do.

Comment: What you're describing is a proxy script - e.g. using [fpassthru](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php) (there are many ways to do it, be wary of choosing a solution which requires loading the whole file into memory before passing the response onto the client).

Comment: @AD7six could you please put this as an answer, it is a correct one and all works like a treat! :)

Comment: @Ondrej you've done the leg work - copy and paste it into an answer and accept it =). I have never had the need to do exactly what you're doing so I could easily (and this is why there wasn't an answer in the first place) provide an erroneous answer, or omit some relevant detail.

Comment: @AD7six ... ok, at least I left a little credit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proxy using fpassthru needs to be done as suggested by @AD7six as follows:

```
$handle = @fopen('file path or in this case url to file on S3', 'rb');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate'); 
header('Pragma: no-cache'); //keeps ie happy
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=app.ipa');
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Length: '.$fileInfo['size']); // taken from a previous S3 API call to get object info
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

ob_end_clean(); // apparently very important for bigger files
fpassthru($handle); // proxy stream file through your server
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the official documentation of S3?

See this answer: [How to create download link for an Amazon S3 bucket's object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663238/how-to-create-download-link-for-an-amazon-s3-buckets-object)

There is no need to push the data through your server to send it to the client. In the case you need protected downloadable items, there is as well a way to give the download link a token that is only valid for a given amount of time.

Comment: I am working on an enterprise App Store for Apple iOS apps (and android too but that is fine with a link) and they require the domain to be same as the server and the server itself is just too small for hosting so many files ... it also requires a valid SSL certificate which I have on the server.

Comment: I have tried to link already but it won't work, the only way to do this is to serve the files from the server, thus I have been asking about passing the file over/hiding the original location or I don't know, maybe mounting S3 as a drive? ...

Comment: I have put all that in my question.