# AWS: Make a file downloadable by https link

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, file, https, download

I have a local .exe file and I want to make it available by https so everyone can download it.

example: "download my app here: https://look_how_downloadable_i_am.exe

If I can update the file with python and manually with interface, it would be perfect ! (the possibility to automate the process and keep it simple if done manually).

It's maybe possible with AWS S3 or/and Lambda.

Comment: S3 is fine for static file hosting. You will also need cloudfront if you want https to work with a custom domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way would be using an s3 bucket to enable downloads to the file.

Steps are:

1. Upload file to the bucket
2. Select the file after it gets uploaded, press actions and select make public

This will make the file publicly downloadable through its unique link. In order to use your own custom domain and link you will have to use CloudFront as @jordanm suggested.

You can also use a python script to update or download your file, you can find demo codes and documentations in Reference 3

Reference 1: [How to create download link for an Amazon S3 bucket's object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663238/how-to-create-download-link-for-an-amazon-s3-buckets-object) 
Reference 2: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/ 
Reference 3: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/code-catalog-python-example_code-s3.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use boto3 to programmatically [upload a local file to a bucket](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html), than just edit the buckets permissions to allow public read. Or instead of editing the buckets permissions, when uploading the file just edit the ACL `s3.upload_file(upload_path, "bucket-name", file-key, ExtraArgs={'ACL': "public-read"})`

upload_path just being the local file path, and file-key being the object name