# Download iOS dependencies from S3 bucket

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, dependency-management, carthage

Is there iOS dependency manager support to download dependencies from the S3 bucket?
I tried to use Carthage, it's working with public files.

My requirement is to download dependency from S3 bucket which is not public.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The closest solution to your question may be this tech: `SPM Binary Frameworks`, this is the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/distributing-binary-frameworks-as-swift-packages) to it.

```
    targets: [
    // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
    // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
    .target(
        name: "MyLibrary"
    ),
    .binaryTarget(
        name: "SomeRemoteBinaryPackage",
        url: "https://url/to/some/remote/xcframework.zip",
        checksum: "The checksum of the ZIP archive that contains the XCFramework."
    ),
    .binaryTarget(
        name: "SomeLocalBinaryPackage",
        path: "path/to/some.xcframework"
    )
    .testTarget(
        name: "MyLibraryTests",
        dependencies: ["MyLibrary"]),
    ]
```

Did you see this part: `url: "https://url/to/some/remote/xcframework.zip"`?
In SPM, you can compress any `xcframwork` as a zip file and host it in any publicly available location. Then SPM can download them as zip file and automatically load the `xcframework` inside it.

> When you host the binaries on a server, create a ZIP archive with the XCFramework in its root directory and make it available publicly.

So according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663238/how-to-create-download-link-for-an-amazon-s3-buckets-object), I can see you can generate a downloadable URL in S3.

So, try this: `build your dependency as an xcframwork` -> `calculate its checksum` -> `upload to s3` -> `try to generate a downloadable URL in S3`.

Comment below if you have met some troubles.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am able to get framework from the S3 bucket if it has public access. Challenge is to access secure objects from S3.

Comment: Is it possible to embed your credentials in the HTTPS GET request? Since your build system is not exposed to the outside world.

Comment: It is not possible to embed S3 credentials in HTTP get request.

Comment: Take a look at SPM artifact bundles: https://theswiftdev.com/introduction-to-spm-artifact-bundles/ which can generate an executable in your package. Then maybe you can do the auth job in the artifact target executable.