# Download file from s3 bucket in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-s3

Below is my url which fetches image from the amazon s3 bucket. Now I want to download that image using php script.

Url: https://phoenix-contents-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/qa/5/image/png/6457f68a6cb14a726c9a71211ba6ee3e.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20180912T091405Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=3599&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJHGHQT6GRAOR5YRA%2F20180912%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=7fce57134968b6c82661326d2b40fead3263f65e7e9b37dc7552433096af8568

This is my code which is working only with url where url ends with file name with extension but not with s3 bucket url.

```
        $url = 'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4';
        $file_name = basename($url);

        $source_dir_name = rand(1,10000);
        $source_dir_path = DOCUMENT_ROOT.'/temp_download/'.$source_dir_name.'/';
        mkdir($source_dir_path,0777, true);
        $filePath = $source_dir_path.$file_name;

        file_put_contents($filePath, file_get_contents($url));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389394/how-do-i-download-a-file-with-php-and-the-amazon-s3-sdk

Comment: Thank @user1514997 i went through the link which you sent those examples are by using s3 SDK. I want to download the image from the url which i have given above.